# Problema al definir zona horaria mediante tzinfo en datetime usando pytz.timezone()

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

Me he encontrado el siguiente problema al crear un objeto de tipo `datetime` con el parámetro del constructor `tzinfo` que define la zona horaria. Para definir una zona horaria he usado el módulo `pytz` de la siguiente manera:

```
import pytz as tz
import datetime as dt

zona_horaria = tz.timezone("Europe/Madrid")
fecha1 = dt.datetime(2017, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10)
fecha2 = dt.datetime(2017, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, tzinfo=zona_horaria)
fecha3 = dt.datetime(2017, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10).replace(tzinfo=zona_horaria)
fecha4 = dt.datetime(2017, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, tzinfo=tz.UTC)
```

La evaluación de las variables `fecha` dan los siguientes resultados:

```
fecha1
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10)

fecha2
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Madrid' LMT-1 day, 23:45:00 STD>)

fecha3
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Madrid' LMT-1 day, 23:45:00 STD>)

fecha4
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Si se imprimen las variables usando `str()` obtenemos los siguientes resultados:

```
str(fecha1)
'2017-08-09 10:10:10'

str(fecha2)
'2017-08-09 10:10:10-00:15'

str(fecha3)
'2017-08-09 10:10:10-00:15'

str(fecha4)
'2017-08-09 10:10:10+00:00'
```

Como puede verse, el desfase horario de `fecha2` y `fecha3` es de sólo -15 minutos respecto a UTC, cuando debería ser +2:00 por el horario de Madrid. Si se comprueba con *timestamp*, se obtienen los siguientes resultados:

```
fecha1.timestamp()
1502266210.0

fecha2.timestamp()
1502274310.0

fecha3.timestamp()
1502274310.0

fecha4.timestamp()
1502273410.0
```

Es decir, que la diferencia entre `fecha2` o `fecha3` y `fecha4` es de 900 segundos (15 minutos), cuando debería ser de 2 horas. ¿Cómo puedo crear un objeto `datetime` de inicio asignándole una zona horaria y que quede registrado el desfase correcto?

PD: Si se crea un objeto tipo `datetime` usando `fromtimestamp()` sí funciona, pero hay que conocer antes el *timestamp* UTC correspondiente con la fecha local que se desea crear:

```
dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, zona_horaria)
```

Comment: Por estas cosas me pasé a [`arrow`](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) :)

Comment: @fedorqui Muchísimas gracias. No lo conocía. La próxima vez lo uso.

Answer (score 3):

El módulo `pytz`, en el método `localize()` de los objetos que representan la zona horaria (implementación de la clase abstracta `datetime.tzinfo`) se recomienda no usar el parámetro `tzinfo` del constructor `datetime.datetime`:

> ```
>     This method should be used to construct localtimes, rather
>     than passing a tzinfo argument to a datetime constructor.
> ```

Por lo tanto, para crear objetos `datetime.datetime` con una zona horaria determinada, la forma correcta para evitar errores sería llamando al método `localize()` del objeto que representa la zona horaria obtenido mediante el módulo `pytz` (la condición es que el objeto `datetime.datetime` pasado por argumento tiene que tener `tzinfo=None`).

Los resultados de la evaluación de los objetos obtenidos son:

```
zona_horaria.localize(fecha1)
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Madrid' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)

zona_horaria.localize(fecha2)
ValueError: Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)

zona_horaria.localize(fecha3.replace(tzinfo=None))
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Madrid' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)

tz.UTC.localize(fecha4.replace(tzinfo=None))
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Ahora puede verse como la zona horaria se define correctamente teniendo en cuenta el horario de verano.

Si comprobamos los *timestamp* nos da los siguientes resultados.

```
tz.UTC.localize(fecha4.replace(tzinfo=None)).timestamp()
1502273410.0

zona_horaria.localize(fecha3.replace(tzinfo=None)).timestamp()
1502266210.0
```

Dando una diferencia correcta de 2 horas (7200 segundos).

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción es simplemente usar el método `astimezone`:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> import pytz as tz
>>> fecha = tz.utc.localize(dt.datetime(2017, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10))
>>> print(fecha)
2017-08-09 10:10:10+00:00
>>> print(fecha.astimezone(tz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')))
2017-08-09 12:10:10+02:00
>>> print(fecha.astimezone(tz.timezone('America/Lima')))
2017-08-09 05:10:10-05:00
>>> print(fecha.astimezone(tz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')))
2017-08-09 03:10:10-07:00
```

Si ya se tiene la `tzinfo` definida se puede reemplazar a `UTC` y luego aplicarle `astimezone`:

```
>>> zona_horaria = tz.timezone("Europe/Madrid")
>>> fecha = dt.datetime(2017, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, tzinfo=zona_horaria)
>>> print(fecha)
2017-08-09 10:10:10-00:15
>>> fecha = fecha.replace(tzinfo=tz.timezone('UTC'))
>>> print(fecha) # UTC
2017-08-09 10:10:10+00:00
>>> print(fecha.astimezone(tz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')))
2017-08-09 12:10:10+02:00
```

Es una buena alternativa para el `localize` comentado por @CarlosA.Gómez en su respuesta.

Comment: Muy bueno, pero en este caso convierte a partir de una fecha a otra. La pregunta inicial era teniendo la fecha final ya convertida en una zona horaria local concreta, fijarle dicha zona horaria. Me lo apunto para cuando necesite convertir :)

Comment: A quien le pueda interesar, otra opción para realizar una conversión como la que explicas sería usando el método `fromutc()` como el siguiente ejemplo: `tz.timezone('Europe/Madrid').fromutc(dt.datetime(2017, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10))`. Suponiendo que la fecha pasada es UTC.

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez mira la actualización con el método `normalize`. ¿Eso sirve?

Comment: Pero al normalizar estás añadiendo 15 minutos a la hora inicial para supuestamente convertirla a UTC. Y a partir de UTC obtienes la fecha de Madrid 2 horas más. ¿Y si tienes directamente las 12:25:10 como hora local de Madrid? ¿Cómo le añades la zona horaria a ese `datetime`?

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez ah, cierto. Olvidé que el normalize le añade el tiempo

Comment: Supongo que al normalizar lo que hace es compensar el desfase asignado a ese `datetime`. Pero como el desfase inicial son -15 minutos, pues es como si todo se desencajase porque ese desfase inicial no tiene ningún sentido. Supongo que `normalize()` es una manera de compensar los defases horarios asignados a los `datetime`, pero el error aquí partía de que se asigna una zona horaria con un desfase que no tiene ningún sentido. Pero muchas gracias porque tu método de conversión de fechas inicial no lo conocía. Me viene muy bien.

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez si, así es. Creo que lo más sencillo es simplemente usar `replace` y luego `astimezone` como lo acabo de actualizar. Finalmente la idea era usar `astimezone` como alternativa al `localize`. Fue una buena plática ;-)